# subdomain to subdomain forward with masking

Tags: htaccess, dns, linux

I want to forward with mask from one server to another server.

In Server One:

www.abc.com
test.abc.com
live.abc.com

In Server Two:

```
http://ipaddress.com/folder1
 http://ipaddress.com/folder2

test.abc.com --> http://ipaddress.com/folder1 
live.abc.com --> http://ipaddress.com/folder2
```

In both servers what i have to do the accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Server one:** DNS server. Point the domains/subdomains to the corresponding server (ip/url).

**Server two:** Web server (Apache, Nginx, IIS etc.). Create virtual hosts/listeners that routes to the correct folder.

Without knowing what server setup you have, it's difficult to give a more detailed answer.

Comment: I have done on server one A records point to server two ip and in server 2 i dont have panels to setup virtual host/listners but I will give a try to create virtual host and i have root access on both the servers , can u please give me your guide example on using virtual host on second server so that i will try it out

Comment: Thanks alasjo I tried your suggestion using virtualhost on second sever fixed the issue and thanks again